# Proving noscript website content for hashbang URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

Lately Google announced it will be rolling out support for _escape_fragment. It was a feature Google used to get "static" content of website if it had hashbang (#!) in URL.

So now Google advices to provide along with JS version of website a static, non JS version for users with no JS and for Google bots in the same manner.

So when person visits for example website test.com/#!/item/2

I should generate a JS version of website and in noscript tag a non-JS version. Ok.

But since hashbang is not sent to server how should i know that i need generate a static website for item 2?

So my question is: how to provide static content for no-JS users in hashbang url scheme website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, but that isn't what Google is saying.

Instead of using [hashbangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), you should use `pushState` and the rest of [the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

That will let you have URLs like `http://test.com/item/2`.

If someone visits `http://test.com/item/2` then your server should generate the page in the state it would be in if they had visited `http://test.com/item/1` and then triggered the JavaScript event that would convert it into `http://test.com/item/2`.

No need to use `noscript` at all.

Comment: hello, i suppose formating stripped some code from what you wrote.

Comment: @tomaszs — No, it didn't.